# how to get the text width?

Tags: jquery

I have the following situation.

```
 <ul>
      <li><span> text </span></li>
 </ul>
```

I use the following jquery to get the text content and width...

```
  $("ul li").each(function()
  {
       var textIndex = $(this).index();
       var $text = $(this).find("span").text()  // this works..
       var textWidth = $text.width(); // this does not work..
  });
```

How do I get the text Width along with getting its index, and text data?

Comment: The text will have an index of zero since it is the only node inside the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

1. You can change your each function to include, `index` and `value`. Then you can get the index of the `li` without the extra jQuery call.
2. The `.text()` call returns the text as a string, strings do not have a `.width()` method on them.
3. I think what you really want is the width of the `span`, not the text.

Try this:

```
  $("ul li span").each(function(index,value)
  {
       var $value = $(value),
           textIndex = index,
           text = $value.text(),
           textWidth = $value.width();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

`.text()` returns a string (the text content of the element).

If by `width` you mean `length` (number of characters) then use

```
$text.length
```

To get the element `width` use

```
$("element-to-get-width-from").width()
```

And you want to get the index of what? From the LI inside an UL? Then use

```
$(this).index()
```

jQuery docs:

- [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/)
- [width](http://api.jquery.com/width/)
- [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/)